# ASP - Jquery Dialog UI function loses functionality after first postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-interface, webforms

I am very new to ASP & C#.  I have a LinkButton that runs a C# function to gather data from a database and those values are then added to a Div which I am using jQuery UI dialog to display.  The funcitonality of it is that users are adding values from the jquery dialog to the form, this function will run multiple times because most of the time users will add more than one value.  Currently after they run it once and add a value to the form, clicking the LinkButton again does absolutely no action.

The project I'm making I originally created with "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" since it was my first web project, a few days ago I created a new one but as an Empty web forms application since I was getting the hang of it and wanted to build the application from the ground up.  I moved all my code to this new project, added all the references and any NuGet packages I installed.  This is when the problem started happening.  I'm assuming it's something small and stupid that I just forgot, but it's been 3 days and I need help.

Some details:

- IIS 7.5
- Happens on all browsers
- No actions are being done with the LinkButton after first successful run-through
- It works perfectly once.
- Using Classic pipeline in IIS
- Using jQuery 1.11.1 libraries

Some code-

**Link Button:**

`<asp:LinkButton ID="addId" runat="server" OnClick="showPopup_Click">Add Id</asp:LinkButton>`

**Javascript code that is called after function from code behind:** (I modified it after reading another possible solution but still no go)

```
function eventRegistration()
{
    $('#addStigId').click(ShowPopup);
}
function ShowPopup(message) {
    //$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addStigId').click(function () {
            $('#newDialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
        $('#newDialog').dialog({
            dialogClass: 'stigIdDialogCSS',
            resizable: false,
            height: 200,
            title: "Add Stig ID",
            modal: true
        });
        $("#newDialog").show();
}
$(document).ready(eventRegistration());
```

ShowPopup is getting called from code behind.

Comment: `$(document).ready(eventRegistration());` <- that is running the `eventRegistration` function and assigning the result to the `document.ready` handler.  Remove the empty parenthesis -> `$(document).ready(eventRegistration);`

Comment: Thanks Archer.  The problem is still happening but you taught me something new.

Should I not be calling ShowPopup from the code behind?  The eventRegistration is the new part I added from someone else's solution.

Comment: I think I know what you're doing, so I'll put it in an answer with some changes to the code...

Comment: Just for S&Gs I called eventRegistration from the code behind, the dialog pops up each time but closes immediately after, I feel like I'm very close but just can't see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have some of the function uses mixed up, like assigning event handlers to document ready and element clicks.  I *think* this is what you really mean...

```
function eventRegistration()
{
    $('#addStigId').click(function () {
        showPopup();
        return false;
    });
}

function ShowPopup() {
    $('#newDialog').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'stigIdDialogCSS',
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        title: "Add Stig ID",
        modal: true
    });
    $("#newDialog").show();
}

$(document).ready(eventRegistration);
```

When your document has loaded it will run the event registration function that will assign the click event handler to `#addStigId`.  That should all work now.  You could have alternatively put the event registration inside an anonymous function (as you do for the `#addStigId` click event) and passed that into the document ready handler.  You don't need to do this but I'll give you an example as it's more commonly seen so you'll at least know what it is...

```
function ShowPopup() {
    $('#newDialog').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'stigIdDialogCSS',
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        title: "Add Stig ID",
        modal: true
    });
    $("#newDialog").show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addStigId').click(function () {
        showPopup();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I think this will help you, but if not then shout out as I may have just misunderstood something :)

Comment: Thank you very much that did work.  Your second example is the route I originally went before I read the eventRegistration solution earlier today.  However, my original code was wrong also it seems because I had the `$(document).ready(function() {` inside of my ShowPopup function.

So either way you were a very big help thank you.

Comment: Not a problem - glad to help :)